# mysterious menu

Tags: menus

I'am struggling with a menu bar, which I'am not able to delete. I'am checked any kinds of options, but I have no idea anymore where to search the function to disable this menu. Can someone give me an advise, where to search?
Thank's a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the top admin menu with Customize, etc. Then normal users do not see that only users who are logged in. If you are logged in and do not with to see that, then click on the far top right of this menu, your user profile "Edit my profile", and un-tick "Show Toolbar when viewing site". Then click blue "Update Profile" button.